# protractor remove custom attribute from dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm new to protractor and my code has a custom attribute and I wanted to remove that as I was not able to test my case with that

```
<input type="text" name="rptdate" input-date placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" data-ng-model="newPatReports.reportDate" />
```

input-date is my custom attribute and  wanted to remove that and mock my ng-model with different data

```
$('input[name="rptdate"]').removeAttr("input-date");
```

I tried doing so...but didn't succeed...

Any help is much appreciated.......thanks in advance

Comment: Decided to close as a duplicate, since we have a working answer there. Thanks.